# new operator isn't allocating memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

This program worked on Windows 7 Pro, but I upgraded to Enterprise.  Using debug mode in VS10. Now an exception is being thrown, and I tracked it down to the new operator.  The line of code looks like:

```
unsigned char* near buffer = 0;
buffer = new unsigned char[1024];
```

Note:  unsigned char* near is a PBYTE expanded.

I thought something might be wrong with Visual Studio 10, but I wrote a test program and it ran fine.

I traced the error to newaop.cpp source file, it doesn't allocate.  I don't know what causes a new operator not to work.  Anyone that can shed some light on this?

Comment: You probably corrupted the heap before those two lines were executed.  As you can see, there is nothing wrong with those two lines.

Comment: What causes heap corruption?  It didn't happen on pro, but it doesn't enterprise?  Should the corruption be in both places?  I've never dealt with anything like this.

Comment: Mismanaging of pointers and dynamically allocated memory.  Out-of-bounds memory accesses, etc.  When you make these mistakes, there is no guarantee how your program will run.

Comment: Misuse of pointers and mismanaging memory causes problems.  However, declaring a pointer then cannot allocating memory?  I don't even have a chance to misuse it.  I've just never seen this type of problem before.  Its odd.  I am unable to post the code for it, but there are other objects being created at the same time, and those don't throw any exceptions.  And it's all the same pointer that causes the problem.

Comment: No.  The heap is a data structure that can get corrupted by misuse somewhere else in the program.  It is `new` that is failing, not the pointer you declared.  If you need proof, write a 2 line main() program that only does those two lines.  You will see that the program works (ignoring the memory leak).  If you plucked those two lines out from a larger program and then posted them here, then yes, all bets are off if the heap is corrupted beforehand.  That's what a lot of persons get wrong in C++ -- where the program finally breaks down is not where the problem originated.

Comment: How does one track the problem down?  I'm not the one that wrote the code.  Does this because a needle in the haystack?

Comment: Welcome to the world of C++ memory bugs.  Divide and conquer is the usual approach (remove code until the problem goes away, then reintroduce code).  The other way is just looking at the code that handles pointers.  Sometimes the easiest fix is to rewrite the code using safer constructs (like std::vector, smart pointers, etc.).

Comment: But the warning is that unless you're doing a code rewrite (the last option I mentioned) make sure you know why the problem exists.  Don't get fooled if you move a couple of lines here and there, and the problem magically goes away.  All you're doing when that happens is to move the bug to another area of your program.  Always know why the bug occurs before labeling it a "fix" (unless again, you do a rewrite).

Comment: The heap can also be corrupted by using dlls compiled with a different version of Visual Studio (or mixing Release and Debug in the same application). In this case you actually have more than 1 independent heap where you can not allocate memory in 1 heap and free it in the second.